# FinalBuilder 7 - Where are log files?

Tags: finalbuilder

i did found a file named XXX.fbl7 which is type is named "FinalBuilder Log File".
if this is the file how can i open it?
once i click it from windows explorer i get "The project file specified on the command line was not found or invalid"

Answer (score 4):

In the desktop application, Tools->Options->Logging section there is tab that allows you to export the logs to text, xml and HTML.[image: Final Builder Options screen]

In a Final Builder Project, you can also use a Final Builder Action to create a separate log file in the format you want. [image: Export log to file action]

Personally I just use the Final Builder Server Notification options to let me know when things have failed, then go to the web server and review the full log in the web page.[image: Final Builder Server notifications]

Answer (score 0):

Final Builder log files are binary files. You can't open them without having the product installed. As far as I remember, there was an option to export them as text files. But I haven't used FB for years, so I might be wrong.